# Throws user is not authenticated to access the Keys in KeyStore in Samsung S10

Tags: android, android-keystore, face-id, android-biometric-prompt

I am using Biometric API to access my Keystore.

To access the keystore, I have enabled setUserAuthenticationRequired to true. 
When accessing the Keystore, I will call the biometric api and authenticate the user. But in samsung s10, Face ID authentication got prompted and authentication was successful using the face.

But, I could not access the keystore. It says user needs to authenticate.

Could anyone help me out for this. Why the keystore is not alllowing the Face ID Authentication to access the KeyStore.